# while installing magento on xampp

Tags: php, magento, xampp, localhost

Error is while installing magento 2 on xammp. Error:'magento.core_config_data' doesn't exist.

I have researched on magento forum, but the ans is not clear.I have saw my log, but unable to solve.

> [2019-08-02 06:25:47] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or
>   view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.core_config_data' doesn't exist,
>   query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_config_data` AS
>   `main_table` {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code:
>   42): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'magento.core_config_data' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT
>   `main_table`.* FROM `core_config_data` AS `main_table` at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php:110,
>   PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not
>   found: 1146 Table 'magento.core_config_data' doesn't exist at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php:91)"}
>   []

Comment: Your database isn't installed/configured properly - however, it also appears you're attempting to run Magento on Windows... which doesn't work with any version newer than 2.2.6 (they screwed the filesystem routing); you'll need to run a *nix VM if you're using a Windows machine to develop on.

Comment: I run 2.3.1 on windows using WAMP.

Comment: I am using xampp. so i need to unistall xampp.@PedroKTFC

Comment: I don't know. I was just pointing out you can definitely get it working on windows.

Comment: @PedroKTFC ... odd - you *shouldn't* be able to - unless Magento have reverted their FS pathing code; they broke it for Windows with 2.2.7 and the official line was "we don't support Windows" - so I installed *nix and haven't tried it since.

Comment: @CD001 I can assure you it works fine. I have some minor tweaks to how I build it. Must admit if I was starting from scratch (I migrated my site from 1.8.1) I wouldn't use Magento. It is absurdly complicated to build.

Comment: @PedroKTFC - literally the only thing that broke it on Windows was a bit of filesystem path validation; it was swapping in backslashes in the paths if running on Windows but then *not* checking that in the path validator (so it was comparing paths with backslahes to the same path with forward slashes)... so, essentially, code they didn't *need* (as Windows doesn't actually care which way the slashes go), which was specifically in place for Windows, was breaking Magento on Windows - and Magento's response was, "we don't support Windows" :| It's simple to fix, but its in the core code.

Comment: @PedroKTFC - but it sounds like it's fixed on the 2.3 branch if you've got it working :)

Comment: @CD001 now you mention it that does ring a bell. I might have created a module to fix that (I'm not at my PC at the moment).